# About background's patterns

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, background

designers,

I would like to ask You, where could I find patterns - backgrounds to download it it is possible for free - for businness cards, posters, logos, etc.? I mean, when I create some design and want to place it/put it like in real environment:

for example: https://99designs.com/logo-design/contests/holistic-care-partners-366442/entries/33839820

Is there are photoshop files or something like that?

Thank You

Comment: Hi ruta, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. We already have a number of 'where to find cheap/free stock' questions here, please have a look at them. Therefore, I voted to close yours. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

I use Subtle Patterns for patterns and backgrounds. They also have a Photoshop plugin that allows access to the patterns inside a Photoshop panel. http://subtlepatterns.com/

This is a huge timesaver for my projects.

Comment: @chad please add this to the linked question because this question, over time, will be removed because it is a duplicate.